# Adding spaces between imports and braces in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm

Is it possible to add spaces between imports and braces in WebStorm's auto-import feature?

**Currently how the auto import looks like:**

```js
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
```

**I want to change it to:**

```js
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Then you have to set the TypeScript code style accordingly; generated code will use the current settings. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/code-style.html

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Yes. Go to WebStorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Spaces (second tab), scroll to section "Within" and check ES6 import/export braces.
[image]

Comment: Note that, as per Mehul's answer to this question, it could be the TypeScript (rather than JavaScript) settings you're looking for. I got caught out on this, initially.

Comment: Just an update on location of settings in v2018.2 Go to WebStorm -> File -> Settings for new project -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Spaces (second tab), scroll to section "Within" and check ES6 import/export braces.

Answer (score 41):

- **For javascript Project:**

> Go to WebStorm > File > Settings > Editor > Code Style >
>   **JavaScript** > Spaces (second tab), scroll to section "Within" and
>   check ES6 import/export braces.

- **For TypeScript Project:**

> Go to WebStorm > File > Settings > Editor > Code Style >
>   **TypeScript** > Spaces (second tab), scroll to section "Within" and check
>   ES6 import/export braces.

Answer (score 15):

**While the other answers are correct, they are not portable.**
You must remember to change IntelliJ settings on all machines you run the project.

**There is a better alternative!**
Add `.editorconfig` file to your project.

On your specific request for "IntelliJ/WebStorm", such can be achieved by putting this on `.editorconfig`:

```
ij_typescript_spaces_within_imports = true
```

You can read more on IntelliJ and [specific `.editorconfig` rules here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editorconfig.html).

---

To give you a better example of what an `.editorconfig` file can do, check the following:

- marks it as root (so editor will not look elsewhere)
- makes sure all files are utf-8
- if file matches given extension gives it some extra properties

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8

[*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
ij_typescript_spaces_within_imports = true
```

Comment: Is this specifically for ES6 Imports? or any brackets?

Comment: @azerafati it’s for all code; you can read more about it on https://editorconfig.org/. Don’t know if there’s any exception to ES6 imports.

Comment: Well, it needs to target only `imports`

Comment: @azerafati perhaps you can eventually think about forcing a code-style to the whole code-base. If multiple people are working on it, it's definitely a good practice. Well, I would argue it's always a good practice having (and enforcing) some code style.

Answer (score 7):

Update `.editorconfig`, add properties for typescript and javascript files

```
[{*.ats,*.cts,*.mts,*.ts}]
ij_typescript_spaces_within_imports = true

[{*.cjs,*.js,*.jsx}]
ij_javascript_spaces_within_imports = true
```

Comment: This answer is best suited as it targets only spaces within imports and not anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the `Within interpolation expressions` in the `Other` section of the `Spaces` tab.