# WebStorm and Angular Style Guide

Tags: angularjs, angular, webstorm

Is there a way to integrate angular's style guide into WebStorm?

In particular, auto imports use double-quotes instead of single quotes, and imports {Component} instead of { Component }, as well as export: [Component] instead of [ Component ].

This is really annoying to manually fix every time I need to reformat my code with `CTRL+Shift+L`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Spaces`, enable `Within /
  ES6 import/export braces`
- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript |    Punctuation`, set **Use**
  to **single**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to solve the imports issue but, for using single quotes,

Preferences --> Editor --> Code Style --> Typescript --> Punctuation(tab) --> Second line --> Use single quotes in new code

Comment: Found this for your imports issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920324/adding-spaces-between-imports-and-braces-in-webstorm

Comment: If this helped, please accept this as the answer and upvote, so I can build some reputation. Thank You